# Clicking on debug in PyCharm soft reboots ubuntu 14.10

Tags: 14.10, python-2.7, ide

When I click on debug in Pycharm, communiti edition 4.0.3, on my ubuntu 14.10, the screen blanks out, closes all applications & reports an internal error. 
How do I debug the rootcause of this ?

```
uname -a
Linux superwomen 3.16.0-34-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 10 18:02:58 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
Codename:   utopic
```

c

Here are my configs from idea.log as ~/.PyCharm40/system/log/

```
2015-05-03 14:31:24,027 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2015-05-03 14:31:24,040 [     13]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: PyCharm Community Edition (build #PC-139.781, 16 Dec 2014 00:00) 
2015-05-03 14:31:24,040 [     13]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Linux (3.16.0-34-generic, amd64) 
2015-05-03 14:31:24,040 [     13]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 1.7.0_80-b15 (Oracle Corporation) 
2015-05-03 14:31:24,040 [     13]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 24.80-b11 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM) 
2015-05-03 14:31:24,041 [     14]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: -Xms128m -Xmx750m -XX:MaxPermSize=350m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=225m -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd -Djb.vmOptionsFile=/home/ekta/Downloads/pycharm-community-4.0.3/bin/pycharm64.vmoptions -XX:ErrorFile=/home/ekta/java_error_in_PYCHARM_%p.log -Xbootclasspath/a:/home/ekta/Downloads/pycharm-community-4.0.3/bin/../lib/boot.jar -Didea.paths.selector=PyCharm40 -Didea.platform.prefix=PyCharmCore -Didea.no.jre.check=true -Djb.restart.code=88 
2015-05-03 14:31:24,069 [     42]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library loaded (64-bit) in 28 ms 
2015-05-03 14:31:24,156 [    129]   INFO - .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - WM detected: Compiz 
2015-05-03 14:31:25,191 [   1164]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - 11 plugins initialized in 825 ms 
2015-05-03 14:31:25,191 [   1164]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins: CVS Integration (11), Git Integration (8.1), GitHub, IDEA CORE, IPython Notebook (0.1), Python ReStructureText Integration (VERSION), ReStructuredText Support (136.SNAPSHOT), Subversion Integration (1.1), Task Management (1.0), Terminal (0.1), hg4idea (10.0) 
2015-05-03 14:31:25,585 [   1558]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=200; buffer=10; max=739246080 
2015-05-03 14:31:25,709 [   1682]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Starting file watcher: /home/ekta/Downloads/pycharm-community-4.0.3/bin/fsnotifier64 
2015-05-03 14:31:25,716 [   1689]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Native file watcher is operational. 
2015-05-03 14:31:25,802 [   1775]   INFO - pi.util.registry.RegistryState - Registry values changed by user: 
2015-05-03 14:31:25,802 [   1775]   INFO - pi.util.registry.RegistryState -   ide.scratch.enabled = false 
2015-05-03 14:31:26,087 [   2060]   INFO - lij.diagnostic.DebugLogManager - Set DEBUG for the following categories: [] 
2015-05-03 14:31:26,772 [   2745]   INFO - pl.stores.ApplicationStoreImpl - 72 application components initialized in 1565 ms 
2015-05-03 14:31:26,784 [   2757]   INFO - .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - App initialization took 4130 ms 
2015-05-03 14:31:28,654 [   4627]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 102 project components initialized in 1292 ms 
2015-05-03 14:31:28,772 [   4745]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 1 module(s) loaded in 117 ms 
2015-05-03 14:31:29,255 [   5228]   INFO - roject.impl.ProjectManagerImpl - FW/roots waiting started 
2015-05-03 14:31:29,315 [   5288]   INFO - roject.impl.ProjectManagerImpl - FW/roots waiting finished 
2015-05-03 14:31:29,740 [   5713]   INFO - rains.ide.BuiltInServerManager - built-in server started, port 63343 
2015-05-03 14:31:37,340 [  13313]   INFO - tor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl - Project opening took 10060 ms 
2015-05-03 14:31:39,749 [  15722]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Indexable files iterated in 6697 ms 
2015-05-03 14:31:47,358 [  23331]   INFO - ns.python.sdk.PythonSdkUpdater - Performing background update of skeletons for SDK /usr/bin/python2.7 
2015-05-03 14:31:47,361 [  23334]   INFO - .skeletons.PySkeletonRefresher - Refreshing skeletons for /usr/bin/python2.7 
2015-05-03 14:31:48,202 [  24175]   INFO - .skeletons.PySkeletonGenerator - Retrieving binary module list took 807 ms
```

on tailing the file, right after the system's soft reboot,  I could locate any obvious crash/warning/failure. Just before the last few IDE restarts, here's what I see.

```
 2015-05-03 14:25:13,758 [226623653]   INFO - openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl - Cache hits:114688, total requests:200317,file:///home/ekta/br/work/src/mobile/backend/scripts/search/data_mining/data_mining_utils/html_prettify_util.py 
    2015-05-03 14:29:05,684 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
    --
```